Impact of torsional compliance on motor control bandwidth
The stator of my motor is attached to a torsionally compliant body with limited rigidity, and rotor is connected to a gimbal frame. I need to know the impact of this compliance on the maximum disturbance rejection bandwidth that can be achieved by the gimbal. I need to understand the implications of this scenario. What all parameters are needed to evaluate the impact?
